# Can I iterate over a data provider for multiple region to create something like a map?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

I want to create a map or list of beanstalk zones I can in my Terraform (for Route53 stuff), is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this than:

```
data "aws_elastic_beanstalk_hosted_zone" "eb-us-east-2" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}

data "aws_elastic_beanstalk_hosted_zone" "eb-us-east-1" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

# ... and so on
```

Is it possible to iterate over aws_elastic_beanstalk_hosted_zone and just get the zone ids for every region in vars I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always loop over a list using the [count meta parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#using-variables-with-count):

```
variable "regions" {
  default = [
    "us-east-1",
    "us-east-2",
  ]
}

data "aws_elastic_beanstalk_hosted_zone" "eb_zones" {
  count  = "${length(var.regions)}"
  region = "${var.regions[count.index]}"
}

output "eb_zones" {
  value = "${data.aws_elastic_beanstalk_hosted_zone.eb_zones.*.id}"
}
```

This will output the following:

```
Outputs:

eb_zones = [
    Z117KPS5GTRQ2G,
    Z14LCN19Q5QHIC
]
```